# Access to the path is denied asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, image

I tried to use this code to retrieve image from sql database and show it in `Image1` asp control:

```
cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from ImageCollection where img_id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", cn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {

            string image1 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(image1, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
            byte[] bimage1 = (byte[])dr["passport_photo"];
            fs1.Write(bimage1, 0, bimage1.Length - 1);
            fs1.Flush();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

But I ended up with this:

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\130301775684384514' is denied.

How can I overcome that without changing the whole code (the way).

Comment: http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Byte-Array-as-Image-without-using-Generic-Handler-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

Comment: Same issue :( access denied.

Comment: Can add your previous code ,it works fine, i was doing something wrong!.

Comment: string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

Comment: I meant to add it within your answer as a solution of my issue.